# How to slice a 2d list into two separate lists in python?

Tags: python, arrays, list, slice

```
temp = [['1979', '74.6.160.107'], ['1979', '216.115.100.123'], ['1979', '216.115.100.124'], ['1979', '74.6.160.106'], ['1979', '192.168.1.33'], ['1979', '74.6.160.106'], ['1979', '216.115.100.124'], ['1979', '216.115.100.123'], ['1979', '74.6.160.107'], ['1979', '192.168.1.24'], ['1979', '127.0.0.1'], ['1979', '192.168.1.24'], ['1979', '127.0.0.1'], ['1979', '192.168.1.118'], ['1979', '8.8.8.8'], ['1979', '64.14.29.250'], ['1979', '64.14.29.252'], ['1979', '64.14.29.251'], ['1979', '64.14.29.50'], ['1979', '192.168.1.11'], ['1979', '8.8.8.8'], ['1979', '2404', '6800', '4007'], ['1979', '192.168.1.24'], ['1979', '127.0.0.1'], ['1979']]
```

This is my 2d list, I want it to be split into two lists for example:

```
id = ['1979', '1979', '1979', #and so on..]
ip = ['74.6.160.107', '216.115.100.123', '216.115.100.124' #and so on..]
```

how do I split it into two separate lists?

further I have another list:

```
dates = ['Jun 15 16:26:21', 'Jun 15 16:26:21', 'Jun 15 16:26:21', 'Jun 15 16:26:21', 'Jun 15 16:26:21', 'Jun 15 16:26:21', 'Jun 15 16:26:21', 'Jun 15 16:26:21', 'Jun 15 16:26:21', 'Jun 15 16:26:23', 'Jun 15 16:26:23', 'Jun 15 16:26:30', 'Jun 15 16:26:30', 'Jun 15 16:26:32', 'Jun 15 16:26:32', 'Jun 15 16:26:32', 'Jun 15 16:26:32', 'Jun 15 16:26:32', 'Jun 15 16:26:32', 'Jun 15 16:26:33', 'Jun 15 16:26:33', 'Jun 15 16:26:33', 'Jun 15 16:26:37', 'Jun 15 16:26:38', 'Jun 15 16:26:38']
```

I want to join "dates" and "ip" into another list as follows:

```
finalResult = [['Jun 15 16:26:21', '74.6.160.107'], ['Jun 15 16:26:21' , '216.115.100.123'] #and so on.. ]
```

how do I join them as shown above?

Comment: Why does your last item only have one element, i.e. `['1979']`? Is this correct?

Comment: @jpp the list is generated by parsing a log file, ['1979'] is an error you can ignore it...

Answer (score 3):

For your purpose, `tuple` is likely as good as `list`. So you can use `zip` to split your list of lists into two tuples:

```
year, ip = zip(*temp)
```

Then combine your dates and ip addresses via `zip` to form a list of tuples:

```
res = list(zip(dates, ip))
```

The above method relies on `temp` and `dates` having the same number of elements; and on each sublist in `temp` having two elements.

Answer (score 2):

Split `temp` to two lists:

```
id = [i[0] for i in temp]
ip = [i[1] for i in temp]
```

Note that in you temp example your last index is list with only one variable which will cause `IndexError`.

Merge `dates` and `ip` to `finalResult`:

```
finalResult = [[i, j] for i, j in zip(dates, ip)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterating through first, than second column values using list comprehension and generator expression:

```
id, ip = ([el[column] for el in temp] for column in range(2))
```

Joining two lists using zip and list comprehension:

```
finalResult = [[date, ip_addr] for date, ip_addr in zip(dates, ip)]
```

If you need to check for invalid values in `temp` you can do something like

```
id, ip = ([el[column] for el in temp if len(el) == 2] for column in range(2))
```

Answer (score 0):

The first answer is a simple transpose. It can be done with the help of numpy. There might be a more *pythonic* way of way doing the task but this is what I've used.

```
import numpy as np    
a = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8], [9, 10]]
np.array(a).T.tolist()
```

gives

> [[1, 3, 5, 7, 9], [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]]

For the second, make sure both the lists are of equal length.

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
b = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
c = [[ax, bx] for ax, bx in zip(a, b)]
```

gives

> [[1, 'a'], [2, 'b'], [3, 'c'], [4, 'd'], [5, 'e'], [6, 'f']]

Answer (score 0):

Create two lists:

```
year = [i[0] for i in temp]
ip = [i[1] for i in temp[:-1]]
```

For the second list one we cut the last element of temp, because it has only year value, maybe you missed it, I suggest you to check it.

Because of there is no ip value in the last element of `temp`, the `len` of `dates` and the `len` of `ip` are different.
To merge `dates` and `ip` just use a simple `for loop`:

```
final = []
for i, j in zip(dates, ip):
        final.append([i, j])
```

And then add the last element of `dates` to `final` like this: `final.append([dates[-1]])`.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to filter the input lists for standard structure and valid IP before doing the split and join, as below:

```
#testasplilist.py

def validate_ip(s):
    a = s.split('.')
    if len(a) != 4:
        return False
    for x in a:
        if not x.isdigit():
            return False
        i = int(x)
        if i < 0 or i > 255:
            return False
    return True

#input data
temp = [['1979', '74.6.160.107'], ['1979', '216.115.100.123'], ['1979', '216.115.100.124'], ['1979', '74.6.160.106'], ['1979', '192.168.1.33'], ['1979', '74.6.160.106'], ['1979', '216.115.100.124'], ['1979', '216.115.100.123'], ['1979', '74.6.160.107'], ['1979', '192.168.1.24'], ['1979', '127.0.0.1'], ['1979', '192.168.1.24'], ['1979', '127.0.0.1'], ['1979', '192.168.1.118'], ['1979', '8.8.8.8'], ['1979', '64.14.29.250'], ['1979', '64.14.29.252'], ['1979', '64.14.29.251'], ['1979', '64.14.29.50'], ['1979', '192.168.1.11'], ['1979', '8.8.8.8'], ['1979', '2404', '6800', '4007'], ['1979', '192.168.1.24'], ['1979', '127.0.0.1'], ['1979']]

dates = ['Jun 15 16:26:21', 'Jun 15 16:26:21', 'Jun 15 16:26:21', 'Jun 15 16:26:21', 'Jun 15 16:26:21', 'Jun 15 16:26:21', 'Jun 15 16:26:21', 'Jun 15 16:26:21', 'Jun 15 16:26:21', 'Jun 15 16:26:23', 'Jun 15 16:26:23', 'Jun 15 16:26:30', 'Jun 15 16:26:30', 'Jun 15 16:26:32', 'Jun 15 16:26:32', 'Jun 15 16:26:32', 'Jun 15 16:26:32', 'Jun 15 16:26:32', 'Jun 15 16:26:32', 'Jun 15 16:26:33', 'Jun 15 16:26:33', 'Jun 15 16:26:33', 'Jun 15 16:26:37', 'Jun 15 16:26:38', 'Jun 15 16:26:38']

# filter temp for valid IP
c= []
for x in temp:
    if (len(x) == 2) and validate_ip(x[1]):
        c.append(x)

print(c)


#filter dates for valid IP
d=[]
for x,y  in zip(temp, dates):
    if (len(x) == 2) and validate_ip(x[1]):
         d.append(y)

print(d)


a = [x[0] for x in c]

b = [x[1] for x in c]

print(a)

print(b)

print(len(c))


print (len(d))

finalResult = [[x, y] for x, y in zip(d, b)]

print(finalResult)
```

Results:

```
[['1979', '74.6.160.107'], ['1979', '216.115.100.123'], ['1979', '216.115.100.124'], ['1979', '74.6.160.106'], ['1979', '192.168.1.33'], ['1979', '74.6.160.106'], ['1979', '216.115.100.124'], ['1979', '216.115.100.123'], ['1979', '74.6.160.107'], ['1979', '192.168.1.24'], ['1979', '127.0.0.1'], ['1979', '192.168.1.24'], ['1979', '127.0.0.1'], ['1979', '192.168.1.118'], ['1979', '8.8.8.8'], ['1979', '64.14.29.250'], ['1979', '64.14.29.252'], ['1979', '64.14.29.251'], ['1979', '64.14.29.50'], ['1979', '192.168.1.11'], ['1979', '8.8.8.8'], ['1979', '192.168.1.24'], ['1979', '127.0.0.1']]
['Jun 15 16:26:21', 'Jun 15 16:26:21', 'Jun 15 16:26:21', 'Jun 15 16:26:21', 'Jun 15 16:26:21', 'Jun 15 16:26:21', 'Jun 15 16:26:21', 'Jun 15 16:26:21', 'Jun 15 16:26:21', 'Jun 15 16:26:23', 'Jun 15 16:26:23', 'Jun 15 16:26:30', 'Jun 15 16:26:30', 'Jun 15 16:26:32', 'Jun 15 16:26:32', 'Jun 15 16:26:32', 'Jun 15 16:26:32', 'Jun 15 16:26:32', 'Jun 15 16:26:32', 'Jun 15 16:26:33', 'Jun 15 16:26:33', 'Jun 15 16:26:37', 'Jun 15 16:26:38']
['1979', '1979', '1979', '1979', '1979', '1979', '1979', '1979', '1979', '1979', '1979', '1979', '1979', '1979', '1979', '1979', '1979', '1979', '1979', '1979', '1979', '1979', '1979']
['74.6.160.107', '216.115.100.123', '216.115.100.124', '74.6.160.106', '192.168.1.33', '74.6.160.106', '216.115.100.124', '216.115.100.123', '74.6.160.107', '192.168.1.24', '127.0.0.1', '192.168.1.24', '127.0.0.1', '192.168.1.118', '8.8.8.8', '64.14.29.250', '64.14.29.252', '64.14.29.251', '64.14.29.50', '192.168.1.11', '8.8.8.8', '192.168.1.24', '127.0.0.1']
23
23
[['Jun 15 16:26:21', '74.6.160.107'], ['Jun 15 16:26:21', '216.115.100.123'], ['Jun 15 16:26:21', '216.115.100.124'], ['Jun 15 16:26:21', '74.6.160.106'], ['Jun 15 16:26:21', '192.168.1.33'], ['Jun 15 16:26:21', '74.6.160.106'], ['Jun 15 16:26:21', '216.115.100.124'], ['Jun 15 16:26:21', '216.115.100.123'], ['Jun 15 16:26:21', '74.6.160.107'], ['Jun 15 16:26:23', '192.168.1.24'], ['Jun 15 16:26:23', '127.0.0.1'], ['Jun 15 16:26:30', '192.168.1.24'], ['Jun 15 16:26:30', '127.0.0.1'], ['Jun 15 16:26:32', '192.168.1.118'], ['Jun 15 16:26:32', '8.8.8.8'], ['Jun 15 16:26:32', '64.14.29.250'], ['Jun 15 16:26:32', '64.14.29.252'], ['Jun 15 16:26:32', '64.14.29.251'], ['Jun 15 16:26:32', '64.14.29.50'], ['Jun 15 16:26:33', '192.168.1.11'], ['Jun 15 16:26:33', '8.8.8.8'], ['Jun 15 16:26:37', '192.168.1.24'], ['Jun 15 16:26:38', '127.0.0.1']]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Problem 1: How to slice a 2d list into two separate lists in python?**

*We can use List Comprehension to flatten 2D list/array. Once we flatten the list then we can check if value of list contain "." in it. If not then append to id_data list, else append to ip_data list.*

*Complete code to solve this problem:*

```
temp = [['1979', '74.6.160.107'], ['1979', '216.115.100.123'], ['1979', '216.115.100.124'], ['1979', '74.6.160.106'], ['1979', '192.168.1.33'], ['1979', '74.6.160.106'], ['1979', '216.115.100.124'], ['1979', '216.115.100.123'], ['1979', '74.6.160.107'], ['1979', '192.168.1.24'], ['1979', '127.0.0.1'], ['1979', '192.168.1.24'], ['1979', '127.0.0.1'], ['1979', '192.168.1.118'], ['1979', '8.8.8.8'], ['1979', '64.14.29.250'], ['1979', '64.14.29.252'], ['1979', '64.14.29.251'], ['1979', '64.14.29.50'], ['1979', '192.168.1.11'], ['1979', '8.8.8.8'], ['1979', '2404', '6800', '4007'], ['1979', '192.168.1.24'], ['1979', '127.0.0.1'], ['1979']]

list1 = [j for sub in temp for j in sub]

id_data = []
ip_data = []

for i in range(len(list1)):
    if '.' not in list1[i]: 
        id_data.append(list1[i])
    else:
        ip_data.append(list1[i])
print("id = ", id_data, "\n", "ip = ", ip_data)
```

```
Result:
```

```
id =  ['1979', '1979', '1979', '1979', '1979', '1979', '1979', '1979', '1979', '1979', '1979', '1979', '1979', '1979', '1979', '1979', '1979', '1979', '1979', '1979', '1979', '1979', '2404', '6800', '4007', '1979', '1979', '1979'] 

ip =  ['74.6.160.107', '216.115.100.123', '216.115.100.124', '74.6.160.106', '192.168.1.33', '74.6.160.106', '216.115.100.124', '216.115.100.123', '74.6.160.107', '192.168.1.24', '127.0.0.1', '192.168.1.24', '127.0.0.1', '192.168.1.118', '8.8.8.8', '64.14.29.250', '64.14.29.252', '64.14.29.251', '64.14.29.50', '192.168.1.11', '8.8.8.8', '192.168.1.24', '127.0.0.1'] *
```

**Problem 2:  join "dates" and "ip" into another list**

*We can solve this problem using zip() function and list comprehension*

```
dates = ['Jun 15 16:26:21', 'Jun 15 16:26:21', 'Jun 15 16:26:21', 'Jun 15 16:26:21', 'Jun 15 16:26:21', 'Jun 15 16:26:21', 'Jun 15 16:26:21', 'Jun 15 16:26:21', 'Jun 15 16:26:21', 'Jun 15 16:26:23', 'Jun 15 16:26:23', 'Jun 15 16:26:30', 'Jun 15 16:26:30', 'Jun 15 16:26:32', 'Jun 15 16:26:32', 'Jun 15 16:26:32', 'Jun 15 16:26:32', 'Jun 15 16:26:32', 'Jun 15 16:26:32', 'Jun 15 16:26:33', 'Jun 15 16:26:33', 'Jun 15 16:26:33', 'Jun 15 16:26:37', 'Jun 15 16:26:38', 'Jun 15 16:26:38']

ip = ['74.6.160.107', '216.115.100.123', '216.115.100.124', '74.6.160.106', '192.168.1.33', '74.6.160.106', '216.115.100.124', '216.115.100.123', '74.6.160.107', '192.168.1.24', '127.0.0.1', '192.168.1.24', '127.0.0.1', '192.168.1.118', '8.8.8.8', '64.14.29.250', '64.14.29.252', '64.14.29.251', '64.14.29.50', '192.168.1.11', '8.8.8.8', '192.168.1.24', '127.0.0.1']

finalResult = list(list(x) for x in zip(dates, ip))
print(finalResult)
```

```
Result:
```

```
finalResult:  [['Jun 15 16:26:21', '74.6.160.107'], ['Jun 15 16:26:21', '216.115.100.123'], ['Jun 15 16:26:21', '216.115.100.124'], ['Jun 15 16:26:21', '74.6.160.106'], ['Jun 15 16:26:21', '192.168.1.33'], ['Jun 15 16:26:21', '74.6.160.106'], ['Jun 15 16:26:21', '216.115.100.124'], ['Jun 15 16:26:21', '216.115.100.123'], ['Jun 15 16:26:21', '74.6.160.107'], ['Jun 15 16:26:23', '192.168.1.24'], ['Jun 15 16:26:23', '127.0.0.1'], ['Jun 15 16:26:30', '192.168.1.24'], ['Jun 15 16:26:30', '127.0.0.1'], ['Jun 15 16:26:32', '192.168.1.118'], ['Jun 15 16:26:32', '8.8.8.8'], ['Jun 15 16:26:32', '64.14.29.250'], ['Jun 15 16:26:32', '64.14.29.252'], ['Jun 15 16:26:32', '64.14.29.251'], ['Jun 15 16:26:32', '64.14.29.50'], ['Jun 15 16:26:33', '192.168.1.11'], ['Jun 15 16:26:33', '8.8.8.8'], ['Jun 15 16:26:33', '192.168.1.24'], ['Jun 15 16:26:37', '127.0.0.1']]
```